`exec format error` when running a docker image built by nixpkgs' `dockerTools`
I'm currently attempting to build a docker image on my aarch64-darwin M1 Macbook Pro with dockerTools using the following nix flake:
{
  description = "Web App";

  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "github:nixos/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";
    flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";
  };

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
      let
        pkgs = import nixpkgs { inherit system; };

        dockerImage = pkgs.dockerTools.buildLayeredImage {
          name = "web-app";
          contents = [
            # provides `env`
            pkgs.dockerTools.usrBinEnv
            # provides `bash`
            pkgs.dockerTools.binSh
          ];

          config = {
            Cmd = [ "${pkgs.runtimeShell}" ];
          };
        };

      in {
        # The default package for this flake
        defaultPackage = dockerImage;
      }
    );
}

I then build the package and load the result as a docker image with the following commands:
$ nix build
warning: Git tree '/path/to/repo' is dirty

$ docker load < result
Loaded image: web-app:bqc9g2xl8j4plw2cka7rmcd0lv8xix37

$ docker run -it  web-app:bqc9g2xl8j4plw2cka7rmcd0lv8xix37
exec /nix/store/bsa1v1mr7c42a0yd90ncnchcs18ylm4b-bash-5.2p26/bin/bash: exec format error

If I attempt to build the flake using the --system aarch64-linux flag, I get the following error:
% nix build --system aarch64-linux                        
warning: Git tree '/path/to/repo' is dirty
error: builder for '/nix/store/j5xd10p9a1jpdcwk47rin3wbzsl6gi4p-pythoncheck.sh.drv' failed with exit code 126;
       last 1 log lines:
       > /nix/store/k4rn5s600l1mvf9l10q13fw1r7r21yi7-bash-5.2p26/bin/bash: /nix/store/k4rn5s600l1mvf9l10q13fw1r7r21yi7-bash-5.2p26/bin/bash: cannot execute binary file
       For full logs, run 'nix log /nix/store/j5xd10p9a1jpdcwk47rin3wbzsl6gi4p-pythoncheck.sh.drv'.
error: builder for '/nix/store/pqz0yipv2xngcsa5jg5z0qqq1yx95dvz-web-app-base.json.drv' failed with exit code 126;
       last 1 log lines:
       > /nix/store/k4rn5s600l1mvf9l10q13fw1r7r21yi7-bash-5.2p26/bin/bash: /nix/store/k4rn5s600l1mvf9l10q13fw1r7r21yi7-bash-5.2p26/bin/bash: cannot execute binary file
       For full logs, run 'nix log /nix/store/pqz0yipv2xngcsa5jg5z0qqq1yx95dvz-web-app-base.json.drv'.
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/jzyb55py52z8n3p1k36f0w054yhc090k-stream.drv' failed to build
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/68aib0d897qfilddzqiy3x55fbic33r0-stream-web-app.drv' failed to build
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/nrzcnhl3v2735zcpj4x4y829nzcqwcvw-web-app.tar.gz.drv' failed to build

I'm guessing this is because I'm attempting to run binaries built for aarch64-linux on my aarch64-darwin machine.
Anyway, I'm pretty new to nixos and would appreciate any and all help. Thank you.

One of the approaches available is to set up a "remote builder" that runs in an aarch64-linux environment -- that can be something accessible over ssh, or in a VM, or so forth; see https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/advanced-topics/distributed-builds
